# strtok and function call

Tags: c, string, strtok

I have this extremely strange behavior coming :

In the below code: If I comment the call to MyLogger then everything works fine that is I get the sTempNr tokenized and 4 tokens are printed .
But if I uncomment the call to MyLogger for logging then only the iteration takes place once and in other testing class with similar code as below there is a looping taking place more than 4 times with redundant info being sent to MyLogger.

So, I checked with Purify tool to determine if there were some memory issues in MyLogger.
Could not find any.  MyLogger is using vaargs to extract args and vfprintf call to print.

I am not sure how to debug this code further. Any guidance would be appreciated!.

```
char sTempNr[41] = "1129Z13589.2.9.10";
char *sTempStr;
sTempStr = NULL;

sTempStr = strtok(sTempNr,".");
while (sTempStr)
{
     printf("in in TempStr[%s]\n",sTempStr);
      //MyLogger("write","","Temp String[%s]",sTempStr);

     sTempStr = strtok(NULL,".");
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`strtok()` keeps some static data inside so probably `MyLogger` calls `strtok()`, either directly or indirectly.

Replace `strtok()` with `strtok_r()` (reentrant version of `strtok()`) to get around this problem.

Comment: That's why I never, ever, use strtok(), and consider it to be the dumbest thing about C.

Comment: @David Like with any tool - if you use it carelessly you hurt yourself (or others), but it doesn't mean you should never use the tool.

Comment: He's right. The problems with strtok() have nothing to do with "careless" users, and are limited entirely to bad library design.

Comment: Thanks that really worked!. Could you please share with me a list of C gotchas/things to take care so that I can avoid these mistakes?

Comment: @techzen There are many :) General rule - if you are going to use the function you have no prior experience with, carefully read man page for that function - man usually specifies what to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Is the logger calling strtok?

Answer (score 1):

Is MyLogger using strtok as well? Note that strtok is not stateless.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like MyLogger is corrupting the string in sTempStr. Try printing it out again after the call to MyLogger. eg

```
 printf("in in TempStr[%s]\n",sTempStr);
 MyLogger("write","","Temp String[%s]",sTempStr);
 printf("in in TempStr[%s]\n",sTempStr);
```

and see if anything has changed

Comment: Even if it does, it doesn't matter as sTempStr is reassigned by next call to strtok().